# Is the download "Electronics -->Arduino" on the Raspbian OS, the same as the "Electronics -->Arduino" on the Kali OS from Offensive Security?

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

Though not a default on either, I see the download is available on both OS's. However, considering the different goals of each OS, I wanted to know if they were identical downloads, or were any pen testing tools included in the Kali OS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I'm going to assume that Kali Linux is based, like Raspbian, on Debian.

In that case use the following command on your Kali system.  If it gives the same description for the arduino package then it will be the same package.

Debian

apt-cache search arduino

```
$ apt-cache search arduino
arduino - AVR development board IDE and built-in libraries
arduino-core - Code, examples, and libraries for the Arduino platform
arduino-mighty-1284p - Platform files for Arduino to run on ATmega1284P
arduino-mk - Program your Arduino from the command line
$
```

Raspbian

apt-cache search arduino

```
$ apt-cache search arduino
arduino - AVR development board IDE and built-in libraries
arduino-core - Code, examples, and libraries for the Arduino platform
arduino-mk - Program your Arduino from the command line
libmosquitto0 - MQTT version 3.1 client library
libmosquittopp0 - MQTT version 3.1 client C++ library
mosquitto - MQTT version 3.1 compatible message broker
mosquitto-clients - Mosquitto command line MQTT clients
$
```

Comment: Kali is Debian based.  I'm guessing the OP is referring to some GUI installer built on top of apt.

Comment: Would you think that, considering everything in Kali is pen test related, that the arduino module, is non pen test related?

Comment: I'm afraid my guess is as good as yours.  However my guess would be it's the standard Arduino IDE.  You'll have to download and install to find out.